# Defining a property for version element to be inherited by child Maven pom files

Tags: maven, version-control, build, build-automation

I am handling multi module Maven project in which I have defined a property productversion which is inherited by all child modules. I am using this even in the parent tag defined in child pom's. The build when ran is successful and the correct version jar is being deployed in local repository.
Problem I am encountering is that I am not able to build a child module in isolation. it is saying "Non-resolvable parent pom" . this might be because of using this property and maven install the pom file in repository and then on running; parent child relationship are read from local repository pom only.

Is this issue addressed in any of the Maven version?

Can we update the pom in local repo as part of the build process?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use ? Can show some pom snippets how you did it?

Comment: I am using Maven version 2.2.1. Example is below Main pom (parent pom):- <groupId>abc.def.ghi</groupId> <version>${xyz-version}</version> <artifactId>ghi</artifactId> <packaging>pom</packaging> <properties> <xyz-version>1.0</xyz-version> </properties> Child pom <parent> <groupId>abc.def.ghi</groupId> <artifactId>ghi</artifactId> <version>${xyz-version}</version> </parent>

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to upgrade to a more up-to-date version of Maven cause [Maven 2.2.1 is EoL for a year now (has been done in february 2014)](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-announce/201503.mbox/%3C20150320213920.6AE4B17423%40minotaur.apache.org%3E).

To solve what you like to achieve you can use Maven 3.2.5 (or [Maven 3.3.1](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/))

Excerpt from the release notes:

> A simple change to prevent Maven from emitting warnings about versions
>   with property expressions. Allowed property expressions in versions
>   include ${revision}, ${changelist}, and ${sha1}. These properties can
>   be set externally, but eventually a mechanism will be created in Maven
>   where these properties can be injected in a standard way. For example
>   you may want to glean the current Git revision and inject that value
>   into ${sha1}. This is by no means a complete solution for continuous
>   delivery but is a step in the right direction.